# fabricjs.com stickman: move the lines and affect the related circles

Tags: coordinates, move, fabricjs, lines

using the ***stickman*** example of http://fabricjs.com/,
I have been trying to achieve moving the related circles when a line is moved. The code in the example is not well structured, heavy & with errors :), as I can not to move the the related circles symmetrically.

If in the **//move the other circle** part is used next line

> obj.set({
>         'left': (s.calcLinePoints().x1 + _l),
>         'top': (**-s.calcLinePoints().y1** + _t)
>       });

- the difference is in the sign of collected information for y1 **and we move some horizontal line visually the result OK**, but in my opinion this type of "adjustment" is not the correct one...

[example code]

```js
$(function() {
  //create the fabriccanvas object & disable the canvas selection
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    selection: false
  });
  //move the objects origin of transformation to the center
  fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

  function makeCircle(left, top, line1, line2, usedLine, usedEnd) {
    //used line - used line for the center
    //usedEnd - fromt the used line

    var c = new fabric.Circle({
      left: left,
      top: top,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      radius: 6,
      fill: '#fff',
      stroke: '#666'
    });

    c.hasControls = c.hasBorders = false;

    c.line1 = line1;
    c.line2 = line2;

    //add information which line end is used for center
    var _usedLineName;

    if (usedLine == 1) {
      _usedLineName = line1.name;
    } else {
      _usedLineName = line2.name;
    }

    c.usedLineName = _usedLineName;
    c.usedEndPoint = usedEnd;

    return c;
  }

  function makeLine(coords, name) {
    var l = new fabric.Line(coords, {
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 4,
      selectable: true, //false
      name: name
    });

    l.hasControls = l.hasBorders = false;

    return l;
  }

  //initial shape information
  var line = makeLine([250, 125, 350, 125], "l1"),
    line2 = makeLine([350, 125, 350, 225], "l2"),
    line3 = makeLine([350, 225, 250, 225], "l3"),
    line4 = makeLine([250, 225, 250, 125], "l4");

  canvas.add(line, line2, line3, line4);

  canvas.add(
    makeCircle(line.get('x1'), line.get('y1'), line4, line, 1, 2),
    makeCircle(line.get('x2'), line.get('y2'), line, line2, 1, 2),
    makeCircle(line2.get('x2'), line2.get('y2'), line2, line3, 1, 2),
    makeCircle(line3.get('x2'), line3.get('y2'), line3, line4, 1, 2));



  canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
    //find the moving object type
    var objType = e.target.get('type');
    var p = e.target;

    if (objType == 'circle') {
      p.line1 && p.line1.set({
        'x2': p.left,
        'y2': p.top
      });
      p.line2 && p.line2.set({
        'x1': p.left,
        'y1': p.top
      });
      //set coordinates for the lines - should be done if element is moved programmely
      p.line2.setCoords();
      p.line1.setCoords();

      canvas.renderAll();
    } else if (objType == 'line') {

      //loop all circles and if some is with coordinates as some of the ends - to change them
      for (var i = 0; i < canvas.getObjects('circle').length; i++) {

        var currentObj = canvas.getObjects('circle')[i];

        if (currentObj.get("usedLineName") == e.target.get('name')) {

          //usedEndPoint=2
          for (var ss = 0; ss < canvas.getObjects('line').length; ss++) {
            var s = canvas.getObjects('line')[ss];
            //console.log(s.calcLinePoints())
            //console.log(s.calcLinePoints().y2)
            var _l = s.left;
            var _t = s.top;
            if (s.get("name") == currentObj.get("usedLineName")) {
              currentObj.set({
                'left': (s.calcLinePoints().x2 + _l),
                'top': (s.calcLinePoints().y2 + _t)
              });
              console.log(s.calcLinePoints().y2 + _t)
              currentObj.setCoords();

              currentObj.line1 && currentObj.line1.set({
                'x2': currentObj.left,
                'y2': currentObj.top
              });
              currentObj.line2 && currentObj.line2.set({
                'x1': currentObj.left,
                'y1': currentObj.top
              });

              currentObj.line2.setCoords();
              currentObj.line1.setCoords();


              //move the other circle
              canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
                var _objType = obj.get('type');
                if (_objType == "circle" && obj.line2.name == s.get("name")) {

                  obj.set({
                    'left': (s.calcLinePoints().x1 + _l),
                    'top': (s.calcLinePoints().y1 + _t)
                  });
                  console.log(s.calcLinePoints().y1 + _t)
                  obj.setCoords();

                  obj.line1 && obj.line1.set({
                    'x2': obj.left,
                    'y2': obj.top
                  });
                  obj.line2 && obj.line2.set({
                    'x1': obj.left,
                    'y1': obj.top
                  });

                  obj.line2.setCoords();
                  obj.line1.setCoords();
                  //canvas.renderAll();
                }
              });
              canvas.renderAll();
              //end move oter
            }
          }

        }
      }

    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Here it is the code on jsfiddle, too:
https://jsfiddle.net/muybien/mzsa3z9L/

I want previously to thank you, even only for reading the question.

Comment: You can use the event clientX and clientY to make the calculations based on the movements of the mouse rather than relative to each object.  Then you just move each element based on those offsets and you should have your result, as far as I understand it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think you are not right. The mouse could be everywhere over the line. Also the line could be inclined on random angle. How exactly to find the ends of the line and after that to put on these coordinates the circles?. Ok, I can do it using sin() and cos(), but in my opinion it would be even more complected and with more chance for an errors. Of course if you want to prove you suggestion, and show me that I am wrong, when I see some working example I will agree with you.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, and forgive me if that is the case, but I assume you want to move the object or the connected points relative to the line?  If that is the case you can use the delta.  Store the last position of the mouse, then when you move the mouse some more, subtract the two positions to see the relative direction (i.e. -5px on the x axis, 10px on the y axis).  That value you can add to the points' positions and the line positions to shift them evenly.

Comment: Thanks of your suggestion I resolved the problem with the asymmetric movement. BTW: The initial reason for trying to get the end coordinates of the line, was an idea (already discarded) to be able to update the related circle positions on rotation too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks of **MiltoxBeyond's** suggestion, the problem is fixed. 
Here it is a working and little cleaned example:

```js
//to save the old cursor position: used on line mooving
var _curX, _curY;
$(function() {
  //create the fabriccanvas object & disable the canvas selection
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    selection: false
  });
  //move the objects origin of transformation to the center
  fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

  function makeCircle(left, top, line1, line2) {

    var c = new fabric.Circle({
      left: left,
      top: top,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      radius: 6,
      fill: '#fff',
      stroke: '#666'
    });

    c.hasControls = c.hasBorders = false;

    c.line1 = line1;
    c.line2 = line2;

    return c;
  }

  function makeLine(coords, name) {
    var l = new fabric.Line(coords, {
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 4,
      selectable: true, //false
      name: name
    });

    l.hasControls = l.hasBorders = false;

    return l;
  }

  //initial shape information
  var line = makeLine([250, 125, 350, 125], "l1"),
    line2 = makeLine([350, 125, 350, 225], "l2"),
    line3 = makeLine([350, 225, 250, 225], "l3"),
    line4 = makeLine([250, 225, 250, 125], "l4");

  canvas.add(line, line2, line3, line4);

  canvas.add(
    makeCircle(line.get('x1'), line.get('y1'), line4, line), makeCircle(line.get('x2'), line.get('y2'), line, line2), makeCircle(line2.get('x2'), line2.get('y2'), line2, line3), makeCircle(line3.get('x2'), line3.get('y2'), line3, line4)
  );

  canvas.on('object:selected', function(e) {
    //find the selected object type
    var objType = e.target.get('type');
    if (objType == 'line') {
      _curX = e.e.clientX;
      _curY = e.e.clientY;
      //console.log(_curX);
      //console.log(_curY);
    }
  });

  canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
    //find the moving object type
    var p = e.target;
    var objType = p.get('type');

    if (objType == 'circle') {
      p.line1 && p.line1.set({
        'x2': p.left,
        'y2': p.top
      });
      p.line2 && p.line2.set({
        'x1': p.left,
        'y1': p.top
      });
      //set coordinates for the lines - should be done if element is moved programmely
      p.line2.setCoords();
      p.line1.setCoords();

      canvas.renderAll();
    } else if (objType == 'line') {
      var _curXm = (_curX - e.e.clientX);
      var _curYm = (_curY - e.e.clientY);
      //console.log("moved: " + _curXm);
      //console.log("moved: " + _curYm);

      //loop all circles and if some contains the line - move it
      for (var i = 0; i < canvas.getObjects('circle').length; i++) {
        var currentObj = canvas.getObjects('circle')[i];

        if (currentObj.line1.get("name") == p.get('name') || currentObj.line2.get("name") == p.get('name')) {

          currentObj.set({
            'left': (currentObj.left - _curXm),
            'top': (currentObj.top - _curYm)
          });

          currentObj.setCoords();

          currentObj.line1 && currentObj.line1.set({
            'x2': currentObj.left,
            'y2': currentObj.top
          });
          currentObj.line2 && currentObj.line2.set({
            'x1': currentObj.left,
            'y1': currentObj.top
          });

          currentObj.line2.setCoords();
          currentObj.line1.setCoords();
        }
      }
      _curX = e.e.clientX;
      _curY = e.e.clientY;
    }
  });

});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```